# RecyclerView doesn't show new data given to adapter after RestApi data request

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my main activity, the initial data c1 c2 c3 is displayed correctly, but after the response comes back nothing changes, although the array after the response is 250 length, and the first member is also correct(it has all the fields as expected), am I missing something simple here?
I thought maybe I should update on UI thread but that's not the problem.
Country is a class I made, with 3 fields, name, nativeName and area.

```
private val BASE_URL = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/"


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)




    var countriesArray: ArrayList<Country> = ArrayList()

    var c1 = Country("111", "111n",111.0)
    var c2 = Country("222", "222n",222.0)
    var c3 = Country("333", "333n",333.0)



    mainRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view)
    linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    mainRecyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

    adapter = RecyclerViewAdaper(countriesArray)
    mainRecyclerView.adapter = adapter


    countriesArray.add(c1)
    countriesArray.add(c2)
    countriesArray.add(c3)
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(countriesArray.size-1)

    Log.d(TAG, "array size 1 : " + countriesArray.size)

    Log.d(TAG, "array: 1- " + countriesArray[0].name)

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()

    val mRestApiVal = retrofit.create(restApiInterface::class.java)

    val mCall: Call<ArrayList<Country>> = mRestApiVal.getCounties()

    mCall.enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<Country>> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<Country>>, response: Response<ArrayList<Country>>) {
            val mResponse: ArrayList<Country> = response.body()!!
            countriesArray = mResponse

            runOnUiThread { adapter.notifyItemInserted(countriesArray.size-1) }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(countriesArray.size-1)
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + " response")
            Log.d(TAG, "array size: " + countriesArray.size)
            Log.d(TAG, "array: 2- " + countriesArray[0].name)
            Log.d(TAG, "array: 2- " + countriesArray[0].nativeName)
            Log.d(TAG, "array: 2- " + countriesArray[0].area)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Country>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("Error ", t.message.toString())
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + " onFailure")
        }

    })


}
```

Comment: It looks like you're only notifying about a single insertion. You either want to notify about a _range_ insertion, or you can simply reload the whole list with `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

I created the adapter again, after the response is back, and it worked. I'm not sure if this the right approach though...

```
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<Country>>, response: 
          Response<ArrayList<Country>>) {
        val mResponse: ArrayList<Country> = response.body()!!
        countriesArray = mResponse

        runOnUiThread { adapter.notifyItemInserted(countriesArray.size-1) }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(countriesArray.size-1)

        adapter = RecyclerViewAdaper(countriesArray)
        mainRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(countriesArray.size-1)

        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + " response")
        Log.d(TAG, "array size: " + countriesArray.size)
        Log.d(TAG, "array: 2- " + countriesArray[0].name)
        Log.d(TAG, "array: 2- " + countriesArray[0].nativeName)
        Log.d(TAG, "array: 2- " + countriesArray[0].area)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not providing the adapter with the new data set. Modify your adapter to allow you to pass in new data. Example:

```kotlin
class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    private val items = mutableListOf<YourItemClass>()

    fun updateItems(newItems: List<YourItemClass>) {
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(newItems)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun insertItems(newItems: List<YourItemClass>) {
        items.add(newItems)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(items.size - newItems.size, newItems.size)
    }
}
```

And in your response callback just call:

```kotlin
override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<Country>>, response: Response<ArrayList<Country>>) {
    val mResponse: ArrayList<Country> = response.body()!!
    countriesArray = mResponse
    
    adapter.insertItems(countriesArray)
}
```

Comment: Also if you want to be a little bit more fancy you can implement https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil

Answer (score 0):

Found the real answer to this question.

instead of

```
countriesArray = mResponse
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

should use

```
countriesArray.clear()
countriesArray.addAll(mResponse)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Now it works. I suppose it happens because the first option somehow allocates a new memory address to countryArray, which is now where mResponse is, while the adapter still has the old address of countryArray, given to him when he was created. So the connection between the adapter and countryArray is lost, and notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't work.

But the second option, uses the old address of countryArray, but only changing the content of it. So after this, notifyDataSetChanged() works perfectly.

I'm not an expert on system memory management and internals, hope I'm not writing something wrong here, but I had a hunch it has to do with it, and this really solved it.

Hope this helps anyone :))